# Memory leak in Node.js outside of heap?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, memory-leaks, heap-memory

I've just fixed a memory leak in my node application which was in the heap of node.
I've profiled that with Google's Profiler and managed to fix the memory leak.

Now my app is running again for some time, and I've seen that the heap size is pretty constant. No memory leak anymore. But when I check my server's free RAM, I see a decrease...
When I restart my node server the RAM is up to it's normal free RAM.
Now I've heard about that Node.js can save objects and stuff outside of the heap. I think that is what's causing the memory leak here.

How can I see what's taking up the memory? Can't really profile anything, or can I?

I'm using:

node.js: v0.8.18 and
socket.io: v0.9.13

Some other node modules that I'm using are: nodetime, heapdump (will delete this, though), jquery, crypto, request and querystring.

Some graphs:

[Free OS memory](http://prntscr.com/w7nnk) and 
[Node RSS](http://prntscr.com/w7nse) and [Heap used](http://prntscr.com/w7nxy)

Comment: how is `Free OS memory` computed?  What other services are running on that server?  What OS?

Comment: I don't know how Nodetime computes this, to be honest. OS is linux, Centos 5. Other services running on this server are Apache and MySQL. 
I've heard that Linux uses all it's memory for caching, do you think that might be the reason?

Comment: possibly, could also be MySQL caching data in memory, or file being cached.  Unless you can not reuse that memory when you restart you app, this should be an acceptable behavior.